# Is there a way to hide a package in eclipse? (maybe for security reasons?)

Tags: java, eclipse

I can't see a package that is being used in one class in **Project Explorer, Navigator, and Package Explorer**. I looked through all the folders, but can't find a package used.

But I can open a class in that package by using **Open Declaration (F3)** feature in Eclipse.  Also Another reason I know there is a package for sure is because I can see the package keyword at the beginning of the source.  Like the below;
`package the.name.of.package.I.cannot.find;`
I can see the variable of that class being used too. So it does exist, but can't find it in the 'Project Explorer', 'Navigator', and 'Package Explorer'.

> Is this a bug? or is this hidden somehow?  Or something else?

Comment: Probably there's a library or dependency you don't know about, and you're just not looking in the right spot.  I think it's literally impossible to hide a package or class name.

Comment: When the "link with editor" option in eclipse is turned on, the class that is currently open in the editor is highlighted in the Project Explorer window. In my version of eclipse, its icon is a pair of arrows, one pointing left and one right, and the button with this icon is found at the upper right-hand corner of project explorer. Turn that on and see where it leads you.

Comment: @arcy  wow.  your advice worked for me!  You should put it as an answer.  When I press the "link with editor"  it took me where it was hiding.  it was a package hiding in the .jar file.

Comment: You can also use 'Show In' in the right click menu to show a file in various different views.

Comment: @greg-449  thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the "link with editor" option in eclipse is turned on, the class that is currently open in the editor is highlighted in the Project Explorer window. In my version of eclipse, its icon is a pair of arrows, one pointing left and one right, and the button with this icon is found at the upper right-hand corner of project explorer. Turn that on and see where it leads you.